# How to differenciate between Public vs Undocumented / Private API in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is their a safe way to determine if class / method you are accessing is not restricted at runtime ?

Or

do these classes have some property which you check and safely avoid using them?

E.g. UINavigationTransitionView or UITransitionView are accessible but undocumented, hence I assume you are not allowed to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm, as the name implies, any method or class not documented in the public Apple documentation or in the SDK header files is considered private API and should not be used for AppStore submissions.

Note, that sometimes you may find yourself accessing public methods on private classes. This is generally acceptable, but it depends on your use.

There are also cases, where Apple has opened API and made public retroactively, meaning you can use a method for current SDK as well as call it on previous versions of iOS safely. Examples of this include `NSArray`'s `firstObject` and `NSData`s base64 API.

Comment: But sometime accidentally you end up in accessing it, Is their a way you can check this programmatically ?

Comment: @user408904 How do you accidentally use an undocumented class? I've been writing iOS apps for nearly 6 years and that hasn't happened to me yet.

Comment: @user408904 There are tools that can check that for you or you can use the Xcode provided validation tool to see if the app uses private APi.

Comment: @LeoNatan Looks like AppScanner is the best one.

Comment: @user408904 Best option is to use your judgement. `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to check programmatically at run-time. In order to know whether you're accessing a private API, you'd need to know which SDK the app was built with, and then you'd need to check every function or method call against the headers from that SDK. Since iPhones don't generally have an SDK installed, there's no way to do that check at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you use constructions like:

```
Class transitionViewClass = NSClassFromString("UITransitionView");
```

then it's impossible to determine it's access level (public or private) at runtime.

It's better to use direct access to classes/methods:

```
Class transitionViewClass = [UITransitionView class];
```

In this case compiler that Xcode uses will show warnings/errors that this class is undeclared:

> Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'UITransitionView'